# Goodle Ads and malicious links

Tags: links, google-ads, malicious

Had my website hacked through a plugin 3 weeks ago.  rebuilt the site with a new wordpress site (hosted on Godaddy wordpress pro).  this was a fresh build.  All the built in malware checks in wordpress plugins and also google's console checks are good and clean.  Google ads wont run as it reports I have three malicious links in my website.  They gave me the link addresses but they are nothing I can locate.  Anyone have ideas on how to find what google found?

Answer (score 1):

If Google's Search Console declares that your site has been successfully sanitised of malicious links, then you can request a review of your landing pages through Google Ads. Then edit and submit the ad, Google will re-evaluate it.

[image]
(from Google's support page, https://support.google.com/adspolicy/answer/6020954?hl=en-GB )

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you gave everyone on stack exchange the url to your website (if it's up and running of course) people could see what the problem is? I would suggest running the links through https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/url as it runs the links through numerous different agencies and could probably tell whether or not the threat is real or if google (somehow) is wrong, and if it is real, if will tell you what is causing it. Another answer that would probably be helpful is if they are external links, or links to your own site. If it's an external link, the best would probably to delete.